# Spring boot application won't map camelCase databse columns

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, odoo

I am trying to map some database columns (which are camel case) to a model in spring, but for some reason this won't work with the columns that are in camelCase.

This is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tournment_tournment")
public class GameData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "partidaId")
    private String partidaId;

    @Column(name = "izena")
    private String izena;

    @Column(name = "IdEnpresa")
    private Integer idEnpresa;

    @Column(name = "jaiotzeData")
    private Date jaiotzeData;

    @Column(name = "puntuazioa")
    private Integer puntuazioa;

    @Column(name = "lanpostua")
    private String lanpostua;

    @Column(name = "jokoa")
    private Integer jokoa;

    @Column(name = "partidaData")
    private Date partidaData;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private LocalDateTime create_date;

    @Column(name = "write_date")
    private LocalDateTime write_date;

    @Column(name = "create_uid")
    private Integer create_uid;

    @Column(name = "write_uid")
    private Integer write_uid;


/*  Constructor getters and setter*/
```

And the Json response that i get from the api looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": 7,
    "partidaId": null,
    "izena": "UnaI",
    "idEnpresa": null,
    "jaiotzeData": null,
    "puntuazioa": 120,
    "lanpostua": "dEV",
    "jokoa": 1,
    "partidaData": null,
    "create_date": "2024-01-30T11:42:58.029886",
    "write_date": "2024-01-30T11:42:58.029886",
    "create_uid": 2,
    "write_uid": 2
  },
```

As you can see, all columns that are not camelCase are present, while the ones in camel case are null. How can i fix this? I am using Odoo 17's postgresql database.

Comment: I don't see `create_date`, `write_date`, `create_uid`, `write_uid` in your entity

Comment: This might be a case of wrong case - as far as I know Postgresql uses case-sensitive names and if Spring doesn't quote the column names then `jaiotzeData` might become `jaiotzedata` in the query and the DB won't find that column anymore. See here for some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive - You might try setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive) postgres requires " to access columns that contain upper case Characters.

The simplest solution would be renaming the database columns to be snake case (SQL default naming convention). `partidaId --> partida_id`

By default Spring Boot will be, mapping the snake_case SQL columns into camleCase Java variables

You should see this behaviour by querying postgreSQL yourself

```
alter table some_table add column "testAbcZzz" varchar;
alter table some_table add column testAbcZzz varchar;
```

Both these have different results. Without `"` posgresql will do all lower case

```
select testAbcZzz , * from some_table;
select testabczzz , * from some_table;
```